# haxe (php) https call: stream_socket_client() Peer certificate CN did not match expected CN

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, https, haxe

I am using haxe's Http class (compiled to php) to send a `request()` over https to AWS. Here a minimal example using the haxe-aws library (https://github.com/Blank101/haxe-aws):

```
var iamconf = new IAMConfig('newbucket.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com', accessKey, secretKey, 'eu-central-1', 's3');
var sig4 = new Sig4Http('https://newbucket.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/', iamconf);
sig4.applySigning(true);
sig4.setPostData('<CreateBucketConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><LocationConstraint>eu-central-1</LocationConstraint></CreateBucketConfiguration>');
sig4.request(true);
```

No matter which service/endpoint I use, the response is always:

```
stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`*.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com' did not match expected CN=`54.231.192.50' (errno: 2) in [...]lib\sys\net\Socket.class.php at line #34
```

Requests over http work. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
The responsible part of the code why the IP address is used to connect and not the name:

```
if(!php_Boot::$skip_constructor) {
  if(_hx_deref(new EReg("^(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}\$", ""))->match($name)) {
    $this->_ip = $name;
  } else {
    $this->_ip = gethostbyname($name);
    if($this->_ip === $name) {
      $this->ip = 0;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the message is byte for byte *identical* regardless of endpoint?  The error message suggests you tried to connect to `https://54.231.192.50/...` which would be expected to fail.  But if that isn't what you are doing, there's definitely something wrong with one of the underlying components.  Please confirm, `bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` fails exactly the same as `bucket.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` (dot vs dash after s3 option is a quirk of this region, not found in most others, but both should be valid).

Comment: good point, but yes, same response, just a different ip address (54.231.193.38)

Comment: Well, something is fundamentally broken in *something* in the code you are using.  An SSL (TLS) connection validates the *hostname* you tried to connect to, against the common name (CN) or the subject alternative name (SAN) in the certificate presented by the server... not the IP address.  Not ever the IP address... so the content for the error message seems to be betraying some nonsense in the code.  I can't begin to guess where, but that is the explanation.

Comment: I totally agree, Michael, I cannot understand why the underlying class uses the IP address. I just modified the Http class to use the hostname when connecting, and not the IP address and it is working now. But that cannot be the solution to change a standard haxe class. Shouldn't be a bug either as I am for sure not the first one trying to send a https request in haxe. There must be something totally wrong with my environment/code.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/haxelang/JMSBpF2sOi0/QpoNEjk9EQAJ and here http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php the openssl extension in PHP 5.6 uses peer verification per default. Hence, switching back to PHP 5.5 is a workaround because peer verification is disabled here. However it still uses the IP address instead of the hostname and therefore does not solve the root of the problem.

Comment: From the look of things `php.net.SslSocket` should override `connect()` to use the host name, instead of the host ip.  The reason this hasn't been caught by anyone else yet can very well be this lack of peer verification by default before PHP 5.6.  You should create an issue on the [official repository](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues)...